# Error using sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I recently started having this error when using the sudo command:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0644, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Any idea how to resolve this? I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error tells you that you need to set the file permissions of /etc/sudoers to 0440. Log in as root or escalate yourself to root using `su` and type `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers`.

Have no idea how file permissions could have changed though.

Comment: Need to be careful about what you change.. If you don't have the ability to log in directly as root, you'll need to boot into single-user mode to fix the permissions.

Comment: True, and actually, by default Ubuntu has no password set on root user, so you probably won't be able to run `su` or log in as root directly. To boot into single user mode you'll need to select the kernel configuration that you'll boot into when grub starts up at boot time. For a basic instructional as to how to login in single user mode, see the first bit of http://www.debuntu.org/recover-root-password-single-user-mode-and-grub

Comment: One of the first things todo on a fresh ubuntu is running `sudo su` and then `passwd`. Choose long secure password and keep a hardcopy of it along with your hardware documents - just to be safe.

Comment: Can't do that because the ironic thing is I don't have sudo permissions in order to perform the chmod command :)

Comment: Which is why you need to be the root user, not an unprivileged user trying to run a privileged command through sudo. If you have a password already set for the root user see my answer regarding `su` above, or if you don't, see the link in my comment about becoming the root user through booting into single user mode.

Comment: Yeah that at least gave me back the sudo usage :) - thanks!